# How to write proper regex finding my pattern

Tags: php, regex

I want to find links with text in big string. I'm looking for such pattern: `[text](url)`, for example

`[Check it on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)`

I have regex which finding mostly good results but there is problem when this pattern is enclosed in brackets like

`This is our forum ([Check it on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) maybe you can help)`

Regex: `/\[(.*)\](\(.*.*?\))/`

I do need to put sentence between `.*` like `.*stackoverflow.*`.

Is there possibility to stop regex after first `)`?

Comment: Use negated character classes.

Comment: ALso don't use `.*.*?` or something like that. Either use the greedy version `.*` or the reluctant version `.*?`. The reluctant version would make more sense in your case but as Wiktor said, use a negated character class as well, e.g. `[^)]*`.

Comment: I think i do need to put .*.*? if i gonna put there some sentence i used [^)] and it doesn't solve problem

Comment: Are you using php or java? Please choose one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) for both the square brackets and the parenthesis. In that case there are no non greedy quantifiers required.

If you want to put in a word to match between the square brackets:

```
\[([^][]*\bstackoverflow\b[^][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)
```

As you tagged php, see a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pjZsax/1) with pcre selected.

Without the word:

```
\[([^][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XUnR3g/1)

Answer (score 0):

as comments previously have mentioned `.*.*?` doesn't make sense and you could use a negaged character class `[^()]*` instead.

```
/\[(.*)\](\([^()]*\))/
```

check this online example with your test data
https://rubular.com/r/lte0WSKCByNXOf

Comment: This works almost perfect, need to put only ungready in first square brackets https://rubular.com/r/lte0WSKCByNXOf so it gonna looks like `/\[(.*?)\](\([^()]*\))/` i found my own solution and it looks like this: `/[\[](.*?)[\]][\(](.*?)[\)]/` but i think yours looks better! Thank you!